# EF Core difficulty with INNER JOINS and LEFT JOINS

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to retrieve some data from a very big database. In order to retrieve it I need to get some data from within 6 inner joins. The following options is what I tried already:

#### Option 1 Using EF Core en ThenInclude

```
    var enquiry = await _context.Enquiries
        .Where(e => e.Id == id)
        .Include(e => e.EnqPartJobs.Where(ej => ej.RecordStateId == 0))
            .ThenInclude(ej => ej.AnswerGrpBatch)
                .ThenInclude(agb => agb.AnswerGrps)
                    .ThenInclude(ag => ag.EnqPropResults)
                        .ThenInclude(epr => epr.EnqPropResultDevs)
                            .ThenInclude(epr => epr.Deviation)
        .ToListAsync();
```

The advantage of this method is that it will map nicely in a Enquiry class with a list of AnswerGrpBatches. Btw I did not name these classes this is just how the database looks.

When looking at the query it is the following:

```
SELECT [e].[SID], [e].[FK_CRMPartner_SID], [e].[FK_Certificate_SID], [e].[createDate], [e].[displayDate], [e].[extID], [e].[finishDate], [e].[fixedGenId], [e].[aName], [t2].[SID], [t2].[FK_Enquiry_SID], [t2].[aName], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID], [t2].[remark], [t2].[validFrom], [t2].[validTo], [t2].[SID0], [t2].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID0], [t2].[SID1], [t2].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID1], [t2].[SID00], [t2].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [t2].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [t2].[FK_PossResult_SID], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID00], [t2].[value], [t2].[SID000], [t2].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t2].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t2].[SID0000], [t2].[aDescription], [t2].[aName0]
FROM [Enquiry] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [e0].[SID], [e0].[FK_Enquiry_SID], [e0].[aName], [e0].[FK_RecordState_SID], [e0].[remark], [e0].[validFrom], [e0].[validTo], [a].[SID] AS [SID0], [a].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID], [a].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID0], [t1].[SID] AS [SID1], [t1].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [t1].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID1], [t1].[SID0] AS [SID00], [t1].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [t1].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [t1].[FK_PossResult_SID], [t1].[FK_RecordState_SID0] AS [FK_RecordState_SID00], [t1].[value], [t1].[SID00] AS [SID000], [t1].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t1].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t1].[SID000] AS [SID0000], [t1].[aDescription], [t1].[aName] AS [aName0]
    FROM [EnqPartJob] AS [e0]
    LEFT JOIN [AnswerGrpBatch] AS [a] ON [e0].[SID] = [a].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [a0].[SID], [a0].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [a0].[FK_RecordState_SID], [t0].[SID] AS [SID0], [t0].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [t0].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [t0].[FK_PossResult_SID], [t0].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID0], [t0].[value], [t0].[SID0] AS [SID00], [t0].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t0].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t0].[SID00] AS [SID000], [t0].[aDescription], [t0].[aName]
        FROM [AnswerGrp] AS [a0]
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT [e1].[SID], [e1].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [e1].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [e1].[FK_PossResult_SID], [e1].[FK_RecordState_SID], [e1].[value], [t].[SID] AS [SID0], [t].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t].[SID0] AS [SID00], [t].[aDescription], [t].[aName]
            FROM [EnqPropResult] AS [e1]
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT [e2].[SID], [e2].[FK_Deviation_SID], [e2].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [d].[SID] AS [SID0], [d].[aDescription], [d].[aName]
                FROM [EnqPropResultDev] AS [e2]
                INNER JOIN [Deviation] AS [d] ON [e2].[FK_Deviation_SID] = [d].[SID]
            ) AS [t] ON [e1].[SID] = [t].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID]
        ) AS [t0] ON [a0].[SID] = [t0].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID]
    ) AS [t1] ON [a].[SID] = [t1].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID]
    WHERE [e0].[FK_RecordState_SID] = 0
) AS [t2] ON [e].[SID] = [t2].[FK_Enquiry_SID]
WHERE [e].[SID] = 1790797
```

But it needs to be one of these 2 options:

using a IS NOT NULL statement but I cannot figure out how to make this one beceause it is deep inside different classes.

```
SELECT [e].[SID], [e].[FK_CRMPartner_SID], [e].[FK_Certificate_SID], [e].[createDate], [e].[displayDate], [e].[extID], [e].[finishDate], [e].[fixedGenId], [e].[aName], [t2].[SID], [t2].[FK_Enquiry_SID], [t2].[aName], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID], [t2].[remark], [t2].[validFrom], [t2].[validTo], [t2].[SID0], [t2].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID0], [t2].[SID1], [t2].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID1], [t2].[SID00], [t2].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [t2].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [t2].[FK_PossResult_SID], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID00], [t2].[value], [t2].[SID000], [t2].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t2].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t2].[SID0000], [t2].[aDescription], [t2].[aName0]
FROM [Enquiry] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [e0].[SID], [e0].[FK_Enquiry_SID], [e0].[aName], [e0].[FK_RecordState_SID], [e0].[remark], [e0].[validFrom], [e0].[validTo], [a].[SID] AS [SID0], [a].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID], [a].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID0], [t1].[SID] AS [SID1], [t1].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [t1].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID1], [t1].[SID0] AS [SID00], [t1].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [t1].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [t1].[FK_PossResult_SID], [t1].[FK_RecordState_SID0] AS [FK_RecordState_SID00], [t1].[value], [t1].[SID00] AS [SID000], [t1].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t1].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t1].[SID000] AS [SID0000], [t1].[aDescription], [t1].[aName] AS [aName0]
    FROM [EnqPartJob] AS [e0]
    LEFT JOIN [AnswerGrpBatch] AS [a] ON [e0].[SID] = [a].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [a0].[SID], [a0].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [a0].[FK_RecordState_SID], [t0].[SID] AS [SID0], [t0].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [t0].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [t0].[FK_PossResult_SID], [t0].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID0], [t0].[value], [t0].[SID0] AS [SID00], [t0].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t0].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t0].[SID00] AS [SID000], [t0].[aDescription], [t0].[aName]
        FROM [AnswerGrp] AS [a0]
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT [e1].[SID], [e1].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [e1].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [e1].[FK_PossResult_SID], [e1].[FK_RecordState_SID], [e1].[value], [t].[SID] AS [SID0], [t].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t].[SID0] AS [SID00], [t].[aDescription], [t].[aName]
            FROM [EnqPropResult] AS [e1]
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT [e2].[SID], [e2].[FK_Deviation_SID], [e2].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [d].[SID] AS [SID0], [d].[aDescription], [d].[aName]
                FROM [EnqPropResultDev] AS [e2]
                INNER JOIN [Deviation] AS [d] ON [e2].[FK_Deviation_SID] = [d].[SID]
            ) AS [t] ON [e1].[SID] = [t].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID]
        ) AS [t0] ON [a0].[SID] = [t0].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID]
    ) AS [t1] ON [a].[SID] = [t1].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID]
    WHERE [e0].[FK_RecordState_SID] = 0
) AS [t2] ON [e].[SID] = [t2].[FK_Enquiry_SID]
WHERE [e].[SID] = 1790797 AND [t2].[SID000] IS NOT NULL
```

Forcing INNER JOINS:

```
SELECT [e].[SID], [e].[FK_CRMPartner_SID], [e].[FK_Certificate_SID], [e].[createDate], [e].[displayDate], [e].[extID], [e].[finishDate], [e].[fixedGenId], [e].[aName], [t2].[SID], [t2].[FK_Enquiry_SID], [t2].[aName], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID], [t2].[remark], [t2].[validFrom], [t2].[validTo], [t2].[SID0], [t2].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID0], [t2].[SID1], [t2].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID1], [t2].[SID00], [t2].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [t2].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [t2].[FK_PossResult_SID], [t2].[FK_RecordState_SID00], [t2].[value], [t2].[SID000], [t2].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t2].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t2].[SID0000], [t2].[aDescription], [t2].[aName0]
FROM [Enquiry] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [e0].[SID], [e0].[FK_Enquiry_SID], [e0].[aName], [e0].[FK_RecordState_SID], [e0].[remark], [e0].[validFrom], [e0].[validTo], [a].[SID] AS [SID0], [a].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID], [a].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID0], [t1].[SID] AS [SID1], [t1].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [t1].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID1], [t1].[SID0] AS [SID00], [t1].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [t1].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [t1].[FK_PossResult_SID], [t1].[FK_RecordState_SID0] AS [FK_RecordState_SID00], [t1].[value], [t1].[SID00] AS [SID000], [t1].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t1].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t1].[SID000] AS [SID0000], [t1].[aDescription], [t1].[aName] AS [aName0]
    FROM [EnqPartJob] AS [e0]
    LEFT JOIN [AnswerGrpBatch] AS [a] ON [e0].[SID] = [a].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [a0].[SID], [a0].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [a0].[FK_RecordState_SID], [t0].[SID] AS [SID0], [t0].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [t0].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [t0].[FK_PossResult_SID], [t0].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID0], [t0].[value], [t0].[SID0] AS [SID00], [t0].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t0].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t0].[SID00] AS [SID000], [t0].[aDescription], [t0].[aName]
        FROM [AnswerGrp] AS [a0]
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT [e1].[SID], [e1].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [e1].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [e1].[FK_PossResult_SID], [e1].[FK_RecordState_SID], [e1].[value], [t].[SID] AS [SID0], [t].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t].[SID0] AS [SID00], [t].[aDescription], [t].[aName]
            FROM [EnqPropResult] AS [e1]
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT [e2].[SID], [e2].[FK_Deviation_SID], [e2].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [d].[SID] AS [SID0], [d].[aDescription], [d].[aName]
                FROM [EnqPropResultDev] AS [e2]
                INNER JOIN [Deviation] AS [d] ON [e2].[FK_Deviation_SID] = [d].[SID]
            ) AS [t] ON [e1].[SID] = [t].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID]
        ) AS [t0] ON [a0].[SID] = [t0].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID]
    ) AS [t1] ON [a].[SID] = [t1].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID]
    WHERE [e0].[FK_RecordState_SID] = 0
) AS [t2] ON [e].[SID] = [t2].[FK_Enquiry_SID]
WHERE [e].[SID] = 1790797
```

The problem is that it will use Left Joins for every Include and ThenInclude except the last one. But this will also retrieve information that I do not need. So I tried to make a LINQ query.

#### Option 2 LINQ

The LINQ query always uses INNER JOINS, so I exactly get what I want from the database. The only problem is that I have no clue how to map this to an Enquiry class where the INNER JOINS are a list within the Enquiry class. Just like with option 1.

```
     var query = from enquiry in _context.Set<Enquiry>()
                 join enqPartJob in _context.Set<EnqPartJob>()
                     on enquiry.Id equals enqPartJob.EnquiryId
                 join answerGrpBatch in _context.Set<AnswerGrpBatch>()
                     on enqPartJob.Id equals answerGrpBatch.EnqPartJobId
                 join answerGrp in _context.Set<AnswerGrp>()
                     on answerGrpBatch.Id equals answerGrp.AnswerGrpBatchId
                 join enqPropResult in _context.Set<EnqPropResult>()
                     on answerGrp.Id equals enqPropResult.AnswerGrpId
                 join enqPropResultDev in _context.Set<EnqPropResultDev>()
                     on enqPropResult.Id equals enqPropResultDev.EnqPropResultId
                 join deviation in _context.Set<Deviation>()
                     on enqPropResultDev.DeviationId equals deviation.Id
                 where enquiry.Id == id
                 select new { enquiry, enqPropResultDev };
```

And yis I get that there is a reason EFCore uses LEFT JOINS but this is not my datbase so I have to adapt to it.

Comment: What's the problem with the very first approach (`Include` / `ThenInclude`)?

Comment: I receive data that I do not want because it uses LEFT JOINS

Comment: Hmm, then start the query bottom up - from `DbSet<Deviation>` and include everything up to `Enquiry`? In case you have all the necessary navigation properties.

Comment: But yeah, it's not possible to get the desired output inside `Enquiry` entity instance(s) w/o support from EF Core of something like `IncludeRequired` / `ThenIncludeRequired` to let the query use inner joins. Which currently they don't provide, may be some day in the future...

Comment: Starting from the bottom up worked for me. This is corresponds with what I wanted to achieve with the retrieved data even better than starting with Enquiry. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx to Ivan Stoev who commented this suggestion.

Starting with Deviation and working my way up to Enquiry did the trick for me.
The query now looks like this (as you can see it contains INNER JOINS).

```
SELECT [t].[SID], [t].[aDescription], [t].[aName], [t0].[SID], [t0].[FK_Deviation_SID], [t0].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [t0].[SID0], [t0].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [t0].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [t0].[FK_PossResult_SID], [t0].[FK_RecordState_SID], [t0].[value], [t0].[SID1], [t0].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [t0].[FK_RecordState_SID0], [t0].[SID2], [t0].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID], [t0].[FK_RecordState_SID1], [t0].[SID3], [t0].[FK_Enquiry_SID], [t0].[aName], [t0].[FK_RecordState_SID2], [t0].[remark], [t0].[validFrom], [t0].[validTo], [t0].[SID4], [t0].[FK_CRMPartner_SID], [t0].[FK_Certificate_SID], [t0].[createDate], [t0].[displayDate], [t0].[extID], [t0].[finishDate], [t0].[fixedGenId], [t0].[aName0]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) [d].[SID], [d].[aDescription], [d].[aName]
    FROM [Deviation] AS [d]
    WHERE [d].[SID] = 5038
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [e].[SID], [e].[FK_Deviation_SID], [e].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID], [e0].[SID] AS [SID0], [e0].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID], [e0].[FK_EnqPropertyForm_SID], [e0].[FK_PossResult_SID], [e0].[FK_RecordState_SID], [e0].[value], [a].[SID] AS [SID1], [a].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID], [a].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID0], [a0].[SID] AS [SID2], [a0].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID], [a0].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID1], [e1].[SID] AS [SID3], [e1].[FK_Enquiry_SID], [e1].[aName], [e1].[FK_RecordState_SID] AS [FK_RecordState_SID2], [e1].[remark], [e1].[validFrom], [e1].[validTo], [e2].[SID] AS [SID4], [e2].[FK_CRMPartner_SID], [e2].[FK_Certificate_SID], [e2].[createDate], [e2].[displayDate], [e2].[extID], [e2].[finishDate], [e2].[fixedGenId], [e2].[aName] AS [aName0]
    FROM [EnqPropResultDev] AS [e]
    INNER JOIN [EnqPropResult] AS [e0] ON [e].[FK_EnqPropResult_SID] = [e0].[SID]
    INNER JOIN [AnswerGrp] AS [a] ON [e0].[FK_AnswerGrp_SID] = [a].[SID]
    INNER JOIN [AnswerGrpBatch] AS [a0] ON [a].[FK_AnswerGrpBatch_SID] = [a0].[SID]
    INNER JOIN [EnqPartJob] AS [e1] ON [a0].[FK_EnqPartJob_SID] = [e1].[SID]
    INNER JOIN [Enquiry] AS [e2] ON [e1].[FK_Enquiry_SID] = [e2].[SID]
    WHERE [e0].[FK_RecordState_SID] = 0
) AS [t0] ON [t].[SID] = [t0].[FK_Deviation_SID]
ORDER BY [t].[SID], [t0].[SID], [t0].[SID0], [t0].[SID1], [t0].[SID2], [t0].[SID3], [t0].[SID4]
```